# OSGI Bundle's start() method is not getting called

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I have few bundles with activator in my environment. In just one of the bundle start() method is not getting called. Basically it is not getting activated. The only change this bundle is having is, it is using "DynamicImport-Package: ".
  Removing this tag solves the problem with start() not getting called but this is not possible as all the packages are not known upfront in my scenario.

Can somebody help me, as I am quite stuck with this.
I can not figure out whats the problem and how they two are related.

Answer (score 1):

They are not related. Removing `DynamicImport-Package` will have no effect on whether your bundle starts, so something else must be going on. Do you actually call the `Bundle.start()` method on the bundle anywhere?

Incidentally, using `DynamicImport-Package` is a very very bad idea. There is almost certainly a much better way to solve whatever problem you think is solved by using DI-P.

Comment: It seems so. Not sure about the issue but we eventually got rid of Dynamic Import and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

When using DynamicImport-Package especially with * you cannot control where a package is drawn from. So you will have big problems if two bundles export the same package.

For example I had a problem with pax exam that uses this * import for test bundles and there where two versions of the package javax.inject. As their bundle calling the test saw a different version of the package the service imports did not work.

So in your example it could be possible that you have two versions of the package org.osgi.framework where the interface BundleActivator is located. 
Do you install the org.osgi.core api bundle? If yes then remove it. Only the framework should provide these packages. It could cause the effect that the framework can not use your activator class.

Comment: Got rid of Dynamic Import Eventually :)